# Command line to get what programming language are used in a github repository

Tags: git, github

We could get to know what language a github repo consist of as per shown in [Stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114087/how-do-i-view-what-programming-languages-are-used-in-a-github-repository).

However, is there a way to get this information in command line?

Comment: Amy command line command or via the Git binary cli ?

Comment: If you want precalculated values instead of computing them again the REST API might help: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages

Answer (score 4):

Yes. GitHub [uses](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-repository-languages) the [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) to determine repository languages. You can install and run linguist locally from the command line.

In your repository, run:

```
github-linguist --breakdown
```

Further details and help can be found [here](https://github.com/github/linguist#command-line-usage).